# How to remove app shortcuts from default opening types?

Tags: default-applications

I like to remove some of my app shortcuts from default opening types, such as some app I already removed like browsers (some Chinese browsers I downloaded when my Chrome had some issue in China) but still would show up when I click on a web shortcut (and it prevent me from selecting Chrome as my default browser). And some duplicated shortcuts like wifi assistance (when I want to open wifi setting it will show two of them). And some shortcuts I don't even think they are in the correct category like Taobao (a Chinese shopping app) would want to be open when I open a web link or a photo.

P.S., looks like Chinese app makers really mess up your Android system with tons of random default app shortcuts.

Comment: The OS should not be suggesting default apps that are not installed. When you say that you "removed" the app, did you clear the cache, data and defaults when uninstalling? Or did you just remove the icon from the desktop and the app is actually still installed? Have you also tried a reboot? Although I'm not aware of a problem with "lingering" apps, I have not installed many questionable apps that may cause problems. Can you also please let us know what device and OS you're using? Maybe it's a device-specific problem. Thanks!

Comment: It's Samsung S6 running Wanam Lite 3.3 (also tested on Stock, and Samsung internal developer ROM). Removed means uninstalled with cache flashed. Besides there is same app showing up as two apps with system suggestions and invisible suggestions that prevent system from setting default app.

Answer (score 0):

You normally cannot adjust default applications individually once they have been set. The best option would be to navigate to the app in the `Application Manager` and press they `Clear Defaults` button. You will need to set other default for the app again, but it will clear out the defaults you don't want as well.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: You misunderstood it completely. I want to remove an app from a default type (from being able to be set as one of the default apps).

Comment: @AeroWang I don't think this is a matter of my misunderstanding it completely. I will add a comment to your original post in order to clarify some things.